# Deactivate it at will

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In our app I would like to present the user so he can deactivate GCM so that no more messages are received.

How can I do that/? I tried calling the 
    GCMRegistrar.unregister()
but the broadcast receiver still gives me messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things. First one is when the user disable the GCM service, the app should send to your server a message to update a true/false field in your DB and when you send a new notification push, you only send the notification token to the devices are enabled.

Or, I don't test this solution. When you'll generate the notification in the device, you'll check if the user disabled the notification. If the user does, the notification won't be created (With a if sentence). You should use to save this functionality a shared preference.

Comment: We will implement the first option. The second is a problem because the GCM is set to launch at boot so since the process is not active it it has no way of knowing if the user wants the notification or not since everything is null at that time.